# Can't install Swift 4 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, swift4, vapor

I've been trying to install Swift 4 on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine using terminal but I keep getting this error ..

```
swift: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by swift)
swift: relocation error: swift: symbol _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED2Ev, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
```

I've tried [this tutorial](https://itsfoss.com/use-swift-linux/).

Comment: You should try asking in here instead: https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to install Swift? If you install it from the Vapor repo it will download all the required dependencies as well https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/getting-started/install-on-ubuntu/

Comment: I already know what that is, that is actually my plan, but you must install Swift first, then Vapor. By the way, they don't tell you how to install Swift in their docs.
Thanks anyway :]

Comment: If you just do `sudo apt-get install vapor` it will automatically install Swift for you! But you can also do `sudo apt-get install swift` using the Vapor APT repo and it should work fine

Comment: `sudo apt-get install swift` is going to install python-swift, I have no idea what is that but that's what it says when I do that command.

`sudo apt-get install vapor` gives me this error `E: Unable to locate package vapor`

Comment: Have you added the Vapor APT repo?

Comment: I just did, and it worked (kinda). It seems like I installed Vapor but not Swift, I don't know how is that even possible, but I just did it.

Comment: @Nickelz Swift is also a dependency of Vapor, so it's automatically installed.

There is more information of the APT on https://github.com/vapor/apt that includes all packages in the repo, setup guides and much more :)

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I had this exact error and it turns out...I'm a dummy! I was trying to use the wrong distro. I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and had erroneously downloaded Swift for Unbuntu 18.04.

I removed that version and redownloaded at 14.04 and all is well.